# S9 miner shipping time

Tags: mining-hardware

I am having a hard time locating the estimated shipping time for the S9 miner. Estimated shipping dates are listed on the website but delivery times by country are not. How long does shipping take to each of the Group of Eight territories?

https://enshop.bitmain.com/product.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading that some will ship June 12th:
http://themerkle.com/ologies-unveils-first-commercially-available-16nm-bitcoin-miner/

Delivery time is sure to vary based on where you live. Based on the selling price I perhaps some sort of delivery tracking would be an option